# Calcular Data de Início de Curso no Google Sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-sheets, fórmula

Preciso de uma formula de google sheets que retorne a data de início de um curso, sabendo que a data final do curso está populada na celula C3 e a quantidade de dias de aula está na celula C4. Esse curso não tem aula nos dias de domingo, então só podemos considerar aulas de segunda a sabado.

Tentei a formula abaixo, mas o google sheets diz que deu erro.

=WORKDAY.INTL(C3-C4 ,1,"1111110")

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também ja tentei mais de um milhão de variações com dicas do ChatGPT, mas nada está dando certo! kkkkk

**[Link para a planilha que estou testando](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qi865m4sQ_5hpODe2pBdnIOTM3JhUmtQ7asRMK4ODNg/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: Se possível, edite a pergunta com um exemplo dos dados contidos nessas células, inclusive informando qual o tipo de dado.

Answer (score 0):

Use a formula WORKDAY.INTL, e ao inves de colocar os dias de curso como positivo, acrescente o - (negativo) e vai funcionar. Não esquece de criar uma coluna de feriados do ano, pois se não irá interferir na contagem.

[Imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He3YA.png)

Formula:
=WORKDAY.INTL(B1;-D1;1;F:F)

Explicando:
=WORKDAY.INTL("DATA FINAL";SIMBOLO DE - E DIAS; QUANTIDADE DE FINS DE SEMANA, NO SEU CASO SOMENTE DOMINGO;FERIADOS NO ANO)

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).